# How do I physically prevent someone from unplugging the power cable from a desktop computer?

Tags: power-supply, desktop-computer

Similar to this question: [How do I physically prevent people from unplugging an Ethernet cable?](https://superuser.com/questions/544533/how-do-i-physically-prevent-people-from-unplugging-an-ethernet-cable)

I have a security camera system that runs on a desktop PC in the backroom of my office. How could I physically prevent someone from simply unplugging the power cable from the PSU if they wanted to engage in...shenanigans, off camera?

I understand that cutting the power is not the only method of stopping the video recording, but someone of lower intelligence might think that's their only option.

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Keep it behind a locked door. If someone really wants to turn it off they will just cut the power to the building. Or disable the camera with a can of spray paint.

Comment: @DavidPostill I was just about to edit the question addressing that. Unfortunately there is no room I can lock it in. Relatively small office. But you make a solid point.

Comment: So they can't unplug it, but they can smash it, press the power button, cut the power cable, did I mention smash it?

Comment: You can build a cabinet easily enough, provide air flow, place cable in cabinet so they can't pull it easily

Comment: Whatever "bandaid" pevention scheme you come up with, that will only prompt a different tactic.  The proven deterrent is a physically secured room.  Security devices only deter honest thieves

Comment: Cabinet still has a power cord plugged into a wall socket which can be unplugged.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aside from the permanent solution of superglue there is the option of [locking IEC connectors](http://uk.farnell.com/schaffner/il13-uk1-h05-3100-200/lead-locking-uk-plug-2m-blk/dp/2063262):

[image]

The little red "button" you see is a small pull-back lever that releases a friction-lock that holds the ground pin.

This might be enough to deter "simple" people from simply pulling the cord as it's not immediately obvious that it is a lever to release, especially if the lever is facing downwards when plugged in to your PSU.  It doesn't stop them from pulling to cord from the wall, though something for that might be a [plug cover style device](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Pro-Elec-Pluglock-plug-lock-office/dp/B002J9NOLM):

[image]

At the very least these will prevent anyone "accidentally" knocking the leads out as there is some very definite positive action that has to be undertaken to remove them.  If someone goes into the room and the system "just stopped working" then you can say with almost complete certainty that the person had to have done something to make it happen.

Answer (score 2):

As @sawdust said, you really need to restrict physical access.

If someone has direct physical access to the box, I'm pretty sure they need the ability to turn it off from a "Health and Safety" / government compliance regulations point of view.

You do have a few other options you can explore - but they are "not mainstream" solutions:

1. If your government (or you) don't care about regs, you could, or could
   get an electrician to solder a cable directly onto the PSU motherboard
   and the other end into the wall.  You would also need to ensure the
   case is locked down (some PC's will let you fit a padlock) and the power
   button disconnected)
2. You may be able to purchase a PSU with a [built in UPS](http://www.nipron.com/dc_ups/) - add these to
    the physical restrictions above and you may get somewhere - at least
    this could work until the UPS runs out.
3. Magic - Use the art of redirection.  Maybe have a flash looking server
   which everyone things is doing the work, when you have something like a
   an Intel NUC, Edison or some other small form factor PC actually doing
   the work - and disguised as a hard drive or book or something.
4. Wire up a battery powered alarm into the wall socket to a trigger 
   which detects when the power is removed. Make sure it is loud and has a 
   conspicuous light to act as a deterrent.
5. Get a dummy camera with battery powered LED, and make a point of showing
   dumb employees that even without power to the PC the camera still records
   and "uploads to the server later".