# How to stop people disconnecting from Ab Tutor (Pulling out Ethernert)

Tags: networking, ethernet

*Please see my other question [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1284571/how-to-stop-people-disconnecting-from-ab-tutor-safe-mode): I was asked to use two questions [here](https://superuser.com/posts/comments/1899472?noredirect=1)*

Our school is running a software called [ABTutor](https://www.abtutor.com/) which allows the IT mointers to view the screens and record a log of what people are viewing at break and lunch. This is one way people can get past it.

**Pulling out Ethernet Cable**

If the student pulls out the Ethernet cable it disconnects from ABTutor and we lose control of that students. The student is still controlled by the network sercurity, however we do not have the ability to control them through ABTutor.
Even if they replace the Ethernet cable, there is no access to that computer until it is restarted.

This means that there is no ability to stop people from using their computer for non work-related tasks, as well as not being able to force-log off their computer when the room is closed.

The room is unstaffed at lunch leaving the IT monitors (other students) in control of AB Tutor. This means that there is not much that can be done in the way of physically removing the person from the room, as well as physically turning off their comptuer.

I have viewed [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/544533/how-do-i-physically-prevent-people-from-unplugging-an-ethernet-cable) on the site which explains how to stop people pulling out the Ethernet, some of the suggestions there would be impractical, considering the environment and budget limitations, which is why I feel the need to ask this separately.

Is there any way of locking or shutting down a computer if the Ethernet is pulled out. This would stop the student being able to access their computer when it is not connected to AB Tutor.

Comment: Please ask two separate questions. Since your question has not received any answers yet, you can [edit] out one of the questions and ask another for the second.

Comment: @TwistyImpersonator, I have attempted to do this, the second question can be found [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1284571/how-to-stop-people-disconnecting-from-ab-tutor-safe-mode)

Comment: Good.  May I additionally suggest that you rewrite this question to focus on asking *how to lock or restart the computer when the Ethernet cable is disconnected*? You can (and should) include details about *why* you are asking, namely because of the problems with ABTutor...but asking about how to stop people from disconnecting ABTutor is likely to get your question closed as too broad.  Also see the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/271445).

Comment: Your organization is attempting to enforce acceptable use policy by purely technical means. That is insufficient. They need more staff to monitor the students.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve this problem we have used an inbuilt tool with AB Tutor which allows us to select different policies.

If the network is disconnected, the computer is automatically put in "demo mode" where a screen comes across saying to plug the Ethernet back in. The computer is automatically frozen, so it remains connected to AB Tutor even with the Ethernet out.

Once the Ethernet is plugged in, connection is restored to AB Tutor.

Answer (score 2):

There are three solutions: software, hardware or organizational

1. Software: the monitoring software has to make sure that it is connected to the monitoring master at all times and lock the computer if it isn't; the software you're using doesn't seem to be very suitable if the connection breaks when you disconnect & reconnect
2. Hardware: use locking clamps for the Ethernet ports so that you can't pull the cable without a special tool
3. Organization: students pulling the cable must be reprimanded in an escalating fashion